# Zend_Navigation_Page and onclick attribute?

Tags: zend-framework, onclick

I've been asked to add some Google event tracking to a link on a site I'm 'fixing'.
This relies on the 'onclick' attribute and the ZEND framework (1.11.11) application seems to generate those links as described below.
I can't find out how to add custom attributes to this function, specifically, 'onclick'.
Is this even possible? I've never got along with Zend and any gurus out there will probably know far better than I if it's even possible.

```
/**
 * @return Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri
 */
public function getBrochurePageUri()
{
    return new Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri(array(
            'label' => 'Brochure request',
            'uri' => 'http://www.website.com/brochure/'
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: You can't add an onclick attribute to a page element, but that doesn't mean what you are trying to do isn't possible. Some more context would be useful - is this page object part of a menu which is being rendered by the menu helper? Can you post the relevant part of that code?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following:

```
'attribs' => array('onclick'=>'somefunction(params)')
```

resulting in the following:

```
return new Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri(array(
        'label' => 'Brochure request',
        'uri' => 'http://www.website.com/brochure/',
        'attribs' => array('onclick'=>'somefunction(params)')
        )
);
```

Comment: Wow, quick response! That sadly didn't affect my generated HTML.

Comment: This is where I'm getting my info from:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.navigation.pages.html#zend.navigation.pages.uri - I can't see 'attribs' there... but I'm VERY happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: Look further up that page, under the heading "Common Page Features". You can have custom tags, but you need to print them out - can you include how you are rendering that tag? Also, I updated my answer - there was a missing comma (so that should have actually given you an error when you tried to run it originally).

Comment: I'm not a Zend person at all, but I can see that the function listed above, is called to a function elsewhere called 'addPage'. The parent function of that is called into the view. If I alter the URL or title of the code above, it's instantly updated on the site, so I know it's the right area to edit.